# What's the medical difference between a "Goose Egg" and a "Charley Horse"?

Tags: injury, cramps, hematoma

I've heard both terms used colloquially growing up, but I'm not quite sure what they refer to exactly. I have an inkling of what they may mean, but can someone clear up the *differences between a Goose Egg and a Charley Horse?*

**Goose Egg:**

I know a Goose Egg is a bump sustained from an injury (I think?) in the shape of an oval (hence, the name). I know they typically occur on foreheads, but is it exclusively to the forehead? What is it exactly?

**Charley Horse:**

Are Charley Horses also a painful bump or are they cramps? Caused by injury or what? Is it like a Goose Egg on a leg? This I'm not so sure about...

Comment: This is a language question, not a health question.

Comment: Well, no... because I'm asking for the medical differences.... Uh....

Comment: Did you read the question ^^?? The only reason why I ask because the only reason I think someone would say "language" question is if you only read the 1st 1/2 of the 1st sentence. Possibly?

Comment: Yes, really. Those words have no medical definitions but that's what you're asking for. They're slang terms that vary in usage from person to person and region to region. If you say them to a medical professional, they'll have to question you further to find out what you actually mean. So I don't know how you expect us to provide definitions for them when they don't have definitions beyond whatever you can find in a dictionary.